# Customisation of the official Selenium Hub docker image returns 'Permission denied'

Tags: selenium, docker, dockerfile, selenium-grid

I copy-paste the dockerfile of the official selenium grid hub from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/Hub/Dockerfile).

I want to customise its configuration files , so instead of copying [COPY] them I add them [ADD] from gist urls.

So this:

```
COPY generate_config /opt/selenium/generate_config
COPY entry_point.sh /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
```

becomes this:

```
ADD https://gist.githubusercontent.com/myaccount/d5203b3e/raw/d8dfcd9fd/generate_config /opt/selenium/generate_config
ADD https://gist.githubusercontent.com/myaccount/gfsfe2fc/raw/fdefe4e06/entry_point.sh  /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
```

I am using Docker-Toolbox on Win10 and inside Kitematic I see this:

[image: hub logs]

Am I doing something wrong?

Am I missing something?

Does it have to do with the difference in OSs ?

Isn't this the purpose of a dockerfile, to make building an image cross-platform?

-EDIT-
Also...
something relevant happens with the Selenium grid node-firefox dockerfile.

From Kitematic I get this:

[image: node-firefox logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add something like the following to your Dockerfile after the ADD commands:

```
RUN chmod a+x /opt/bin/entry_point.sh \
    && chmod a+x /opt/selenium/generate_config
```

This is because when the files are added to the image with COPY they already have execute permission on the host (which is preserved) but when you add them from a remote source using ADD they are not automatically given execute permission.